# Does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator' in MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to solve this from 2 days.

The **error is**

> Compiler Error Message: CS1579: foreach statement cannot operate on
>   variables of type
>   'mvc_ado.net_crud.Models.BusinessObject.ContactPerson' because
>   'mvc_ado.net_crud.Models.BusinessObject.ContactPerson' does not
>   contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

My controller

```
    public ActionResult List()
    {
        var model = ContactPersonManager.GetList();
        return View(model);
    }
```

In my model

```
 public static ContactPersonList GetList()
    {
        ContactPersonList tempList = null;
        using (var myConnection = new SqlConnection(AppConfiguration.ConnectionString))
        {
            var myCommand = new SqlCommand("uspContactPersonSelectList", myConnection) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure };
            myConnection.Open();
            using (var myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (myReader.HasRows)
                {
                    tempList = new ContactPersonList();
                    while (myReader.Read())
                    {
                        tempList.Add(FillDataRecord(myReader));
                    }
                }
                myReader.Close();
            }
        }
        return tempList;
    }
```

My view

```
    @foreach (var person in Model)
    {
        <ul>
            <li>
                @person.ID;
            </li>
        </ul>
    }
```

Am i missing or doing thing's wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Instead of

```
@model mvc_ado.net_crud.Models.BusinessObject.ContactPerson
```

have

```
@model IEnumerable<mvc_ado.net_crud.Models.BusinessObject.ContactPerson>
```

in your view.

This assumes that your `ContactPersonList` implements the `IEnumerable<ContactPerson>`. If not, then you could try

```
@model ContactPersonList
```

however it is not clear what the custom type, `ContactPersonList`, really is.